# BLE advertisement and data packet field values

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How does the BLE sniffers get to know the various fields like the channel number, rssi etc that are not a part of the advertised packet?

EDIT: I have one more follow up question. How do we set the le advertising parameters in bluez? However the structure for this is given in lib/hci.h but that is not used anywhere in the code and also i haven't found the default values for the parameters to know the advertisement frequency.

How can we configure those parameters?

Comment: LE advertising packet has the RSSI in it.

Comment: Can you please point me in which field it is sent over and how can we parse the packet to get it for every packet we get on the advertisement channels?

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications download the 4.1 specs, pg 1220  "7.7.65.2 LE Advertising Report Event".  The last piece of data is the RSSI.

Comment: @Tim thanks for pointing me, i will try to print it from there, will that be for every advertised packet?

Comment: yes, it's part of the packet format

Comment: yes got the prints on the central side..

Comment: please put some light on the EDIT

Comment: Which parameters are you talking about?  The scanning parameters or the parameters when turning on advertising?

Comment: The frequencies and channels for advertising are abstracted away.  You can't control that.

Comment: yes, i am talking about the parameters when turning on the advertisement. And for the frequency i mean the time how often the advertisement event is made `T_advEvent=advInterval+advDelay`. The `advDelay` comes from the link layer, but can we control the `advInterval` to make an approximation

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure... That seems like something you should be able to control somewhere.

Comment: But as Apple iBeacons requires the advertisement every 100ms, so in that case how can we say that we meet that requirement. 
How can we know at what rate it is advertising now?

Comment: Also the TI BLE stack allows one to choose the advertising channel, can't we do the same with bluez stack?

Comment: You'll have to wade through the bluez source code to figure out what you can and can't do with bluez.  It should support the whole set of Bluetooth LE commands, so you could see if there's also something in there to do what you're asking.

Comment: Yes Tim, thanks for your support. I have been looking to use the `le_set_advertising_parameters` structure as it is done in case of bluez-5.7 source